# Is there delay with console.log?

Tags: javascript, html

TEST

```
HeadTr.appendChild(CityTd);                            //NodeHead
HeadTr.appendChild(ValueTd);
HeadTr.appendChild(OpTd);
contact.appendChild(HeadTr);


console.log(contact);                                  


for( node in aqiData){                                  //NodeChild
    var Tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var NCityTd = document.createElement('td');
    var NValueTd = document.createElement('td');
    var DelTd = document.createElement('td');
    var Button = document.createElement('button');

    Button.innerHTML = 'del';
    NCityTd.innerHTML = node;
    NValueTd.innerHTML = aqiData[node];

    DelTd.appendChild(Button);
    Tr.appendChild(NCityTd);
    Tr.appendChild(NValueTd);
    Tr.appendChild(DelTd);
    contact.appendChild(Tr);  
}
```

OUTPUT
[image]

The NodeChild is behind the console.log.

In my point,the console.log only output the NodeHead

why the console.log output the NodeChild

Comment: Don't see one inside the `for` loop, maybe that's why.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync